# adding numbers to file list returned by find command

Tags: linux

I am running find command to get list of files having a particular size and then i save the output in a file, now i traverse through this file one by one and ask user which one he wants to delete. I wanted to do something like add a number next to each file in list so that user can directly enter the number associated with this file and delete instead of having to go over the whole file. Please help.

Comment: Why not loop over the output of `find` and ask the user? If I understand correctly, why not use `find`..`exec` combo & use `rm -i` which is interactive removal which will ask user [y/n] query before deletion of the file. There is no need as such to save output to a file unless you are using the file for something else apart from listing files for removal

Answer (score 1):

```
select f in $(find . -name '*.txt'); do
    if [ -n "$f" ]; then
        # put your command here
        echo "rm $f"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -size 5k -okdir rm {} ";"
```

asks you for each file, whether to perform the action or not, without an intermediate file.

The `-okdir` is a Gnu-extension to find, and not available for all implementations.

Another, lean approach is to use `select`:

```
select fno in $(find . -size 5k); 
do  
    echo rm $fno
done
```

which is a bashism, maybe not present in your shell.

`help select` shows its usage. Unfortunately, it doesn't, like the find-solution too, allow to select multiple entries at once, but you get repeated opportunity to select something, until you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which is quiet comfortable.

```
select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done

Select words from a list and execute commands.

The WORDS are expanded, generating a list of words.  The
set of expanded words is printed on the standard error, each
preceded by a number.  If `in WORDS' is not present, `in "$@"'
is assumed.  The PS3 prompt is then displayed and a line read
from the standard input.  If the line consists of the number
corresponding to one of the displayed words, then NAME is set
to that word.  If the line is empty, WORDS and the prompt are
redisplayed.  If EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other
value read causes NAME to be set to null.  The line read is saved
in the variable REPLY.  COMMANDS are executed after each selection
until a break command is executed.

Exit Status:
Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

This is what it looks like:

```
select fno in  *scala ; do  echo "fno: "  $fno; done  
1) Cartesian.scala       6) MWzufall.scala  
2) Haeufigkeit.scala     7) Shuffle.scala   
3) HelloChain.scala      8) eHWCChain.scala
4) Lychrel.scala         9) equilibrum.scala    
5) M.scala              10) scala
#? 3
fno:  HelloChain.scala
#? 3 4 
fno: 
#?
```

Note that words are separated by spaces, so you have to take care in the second example, if you have to work with whitespace in filenames.